# ASP.NET MVC 3 "Add View" hangs with IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-express

When adding a new view via the "Add View..." dialog in VS2010SP1 with IIS Express running my site, the dialog hangs when pressing the Add button. Usually takes a couple of minutes for this dialog to finish ( whereas without IIS Express running, it finishes immediately ).

When closing IIS Express during this hang, the dialog finishes immediately.

Does anyone know what causes this, or how to fix this? Known issue? I don't want to close and restart my IIS Express everytime I add a new View.

Comment: why not install iis on your machine and set up the project to use that. It's closer to the production setup and it's really well documented.

Comment: so your advice is to *not* use IIS Express?

Comment: I guess so. I've never used Cassini or IIS Express specifically because the have problems that aren't immediately obvious and they don't give a close enough approximation to a release environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solutions listed here. This only happens to me when I have vs running for a long period of time so I haven't tested it yet.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpide/thread/d8c6c742-0241-40ab-8cac-dd58fb9a7c61

Turn off "Use Hardware Graphics Acceleration if available"

It's under the generals tab in options: Unclick "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and then unclick the "Use Hardware Graphics Acceleration if available".